# JavaScript native methods silently fail rather than throw error

Tags: javascript, exception

I'm writing a JavaScript library for the sake of the exercise, and I'm modeling the code on existing objects such as Array.

What I've noticed is that methods like `array.pop` (when array is empty) and `array.splice(-1, -1)` fail silently instead of throwing an error. Why is it so? Isn't better for debugging purposes to throw an error? Or is there some JavaScript best practice that I didn't know?

Comment: What language are you coming from to Javascript?

Comment: At least with `.pop()` you can now do loops with `while( x = array.pop() ) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array.pop on an empty array will return with type: undefined.  If you try to use the result it will throw an error.

array.splice will always return an array.  If nothing was removed it will return an empty array.

To make sure methods like this are returning the expected values, you should write unit tests.

A simple example:

```
if( !myarray.pop() ){
    console.log( 'Error' );
}
```

For more verbose unit testing I would use a js unit testing library.  One I've used is QUnit.js http://qunitjs.com/

Comment: That makes sense. But what about some other methods that fail silently rather than throwing an error? I guess what I'm asking is, is there any guideline for deciding when to throw and when to fail silently?

Comment: @flsg Depends on what you're trying to achieve. JS is a little permissive in nature, and if you look into popular libraries such as jQuery, calling methods on empty objects will fail silently as well. Whether you're going to fail silently or throw errors depend on your intent, and should be documented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea why it's permissive? Is this a conscious design choice? i.e. what benefit is there for jQuery to fail silently?